# Null check operator cannot used on null value

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

this is my chatscreen code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:messenger/helperfunction/sharedpref_helper.dart';
import 'package:messenger/services/database.dart';
import 'package:random_string/random_string.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String chatWithusername, name;
  ChatScreen(this.chatWithusername, this.name);

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  String? chatRoomId, messageId = "";
  String? myName, myProfilePic, myUserName, myEmail;
  TextEditingController messageEditingController = TextEditingController();

  getMyInfoFromSharedPreference() async {
    myName = await SharedPreferenceHelper().getDisplayName();
    myProfilePic = await SharedPreferenceHelper().getUserProfileUrl();
    myUserName = await SharedPreferenceHelper().getUserName();
    myEmail = await SharedPreferenceHelper().getUserEmail();

    chatRoomId = getChatRoomIdByUsername(widget.chatWithusername, myUserName);
  }

  getChatRoomIdByUsername(String? a, String? b) {
    if (a!.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > b!.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
  return "$b\_$a";
  } else {
  return "$a\_$b";
  }}
addMessage(bool sentClicked) {
   if (messageEditingController.text != "") {
  String message = messageEditingController.text;

  var lastMessageTs = DateTime.now();

  Map<String, dynamic> messageInfoMap = {
    "message": message,
    "sentBy": myUserName,
    'ts': lastMessageTs,
    "imgUrl": myProfilePic
  };
  //Gentrate the message id
  if (messageId == "") {
    messageId = randomAlphaNumeric(12);
  }

  DatabaseMethods()
      .addMessage(chatRoomId!, messageId!, messageInfoMap)
      .then((value) {
    Map<String, dynamic>? lastMessageInfoMap = {
      "lastmessage": message,
      "lastMessageSendTs": lastMessageTs,
      "lastMessageSendBy": myUserName
    };

    DatabaseMethods()
        .updateLastmessageSend(chatRoomId!, lastMessageInfoMap);

    if (sentClicked) {
      messageEditingController.text = "";

      messageId = "";
    }
  });
}
}


  getAnfSentMessages() async {}

  doThisOnlaunch() async {
 await getMyInfoFromSharedPreference();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.name),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 6,
              vertical: 8,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: messageEditingController,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      addMessage(false);
                    },
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "   Type a message",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6))),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      addMessage(true);
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.white))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
 );
 }
}
```

This is my DataBase;

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
// ignore: unused_import
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class DatabaseMethods {
  Future addUserInfoToDB(
      String userId, Map<String, dynamic> userInfoMap) async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(userId)
        .set(userInfoMap);
  }

  Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getUserByUserName(String username) async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("username", isEqualTo: username)
        .snapshots();
  }

  Future addMessage(String chatRoomId, String messageId,
      Map<String, dynamic> messageInfoMap) async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chatRooms")
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .collection("chats")
        .doc(messageId)
        .set(messageInfoMap);
  }

  updateLastmessageSend(
      String chatRoomId, Map<String, dynamic> lastMessageInfoMap) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chatRooms")
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .update(lastMessageInfoMap);
  }

  createChatRoom(
      String chatRoomId, Map<String, dynamic> chatRoomInfoMap) async {
    final snapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chatrooms")
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .get();

    if (snapShot.exists) {
      //chatroom already exits
      return true;
    } else {
      //chatRoom does not exit:
      return FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("chatrooms")
          .doc(chatRoomId)
          .set(chatRoomInfoMap);
    }
  }
}
```

when i run this code and start typing in textformfield, i am getting this following error:
'''

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets 
═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown while calling onChanged:
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _ChatScreenState.addMessage
package:messenger/view/chatscreen.dart:54
#1      _ChatScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:messenger/view/chatscreen.dart:103
#2      EditableTextState._formatAndSetValue
package:flutter/…/widgets/editable_text.dart:2298
#3      EditableTextState.updateEditingValue
package:flutter/…/widgets/editable_text.dart:1749
#4      TextInput._handleTextInputInvocation
 package:flutter/…/services/text_input.dart:1351
```

'''

After typed, when i clicked sent icon i am getting error like this:

'''
════════ Exception caught by gesture
═══════════════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value

```
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

'''
can anyone help to solve this issue

Comment: The only `null` checks I see are done on `chatRoomId!, messageId!`, one of those values are `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into your code I can see that this function is never called

```
doThisOnlaunch() async {
    await getMyInfoFromSharedPreference();
  }
```

So the `getMyInfoFromSharedPreference()` function is never called
So `chatRoomId` is not initialized and it will always be null Because of this code

```
String? chatRoomId, messageId = "";
```

And in this method you are using the `!` on `chatRoomId` which is null.

```
DatabaseMethods()
          .addMessage(chatRoomId!, messageId!, messageInfoMap).then((value) {...
```

So this is what causes the error.

**Solution**

Call tis method on `initState` like

```
String? chatRoomId, messageId = "";
      String? myName, myProfilePic, myUserName, myEmail;
      TextEditingController messageEditingController = TextEditingController();
    
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        doThisOnlaunch();
      }
      .
      .
      .
```

or just initiate `chatRoomId` with a value and declare them as not nullable String

```
String chatRoomId="", messageId = "";
```

Note that this second solution will just stop the error but your code will not function properly

Comment: thanks for your help and also need to add "late String chatRoomId, messageId = "";"

Comment: You are welcome. Adding late means that these fields are not nullable but will be initialized at late time of the app, so be careful while using them.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you used `!` on a variable and that variable is null. Check the error where it is.

Comment: i don't know how to find it. i completely new to the flutter. Can u help to solve this error

Answer (score 1):

```
getChatRoomIdByUsername(String? a, String? b) {
    if (a!.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > b!.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
  return "$b\_$a";
  } else {
  return "$a\_$b";
  }}
```

Why are you allowing nullable variables if the function depends on this?

```
getChatRoomIdByUsername({required String a,required String b}) {
    if (a.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > b.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
  return "$b\_$a";
  } else {
  return "$a\_$b";
  }
```

}

Comment: if i change required string it's show error: Can't have modifier 'required' here.
Try removing 'required'.

Comment: `getChatRoomIdByUsername({required String a,required String b})`
Check your code you are missing curly brackets `{}`